# Angular 8 dependent dropdown for input boxes

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say we have an array of names like this:

```
nameSelected: string;

names: Name[
    {firstName: 'John', middleName: 'Danny', lastName: 'Smith'}, 
    {firstName: 'Bob', middleName: 'Chris', lastName: 'Lopes'}, 
    {firstName: 'Gary', middleName: 'Tom', lastName: 'Harrison'}
];
```

```html
<mat-form-field appearence="fill">
    <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="nameSelected">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let name of Names" [value]="Name.firstName">{{Name.firstName}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field> 

<mat-form-field>  
    <input matInput placeholder="Middle name" [value]="Name.middleName">{{Name.middleName}}/>
</mat-form-field> 

<mat-form-field>  
    <input matInput placeholder="Last Name"[value]="Name.lastName">{{Name.lastName}}/>
</mat-form-field>
```

What I want to do is when I select the first name in the field the other 2 input fields will populate the middle name and last name from that array.

For example, if I select John the 2 other input fields will have Danny in the middle name and smith in the last name already populated.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? The first part doesn't seem to be valid syntactically.

Comment: The problem is when i select John in the first select box the other 2 input boxes do not display danny in the middle name input box and smith in the last name input box. As far as syntax in the first part, I am not sure what I am missing there as everything seems to compile. As far as what i tried I would say alot. There is one thing that works but i feel it is not correct and does not work for the 3rd input box. If i change the first value in the select box to Name.middleName and the second box value to nameSelected it will populate the second box, but how would i do it to third box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having nameSelected as a string it can be an instance of Name as follow then you access the attribute of the name selected in the 2 others input tags, Also you have a small syntax error in the creation of your array:

```
.ts
// you create an instance of type Name
nameSelected: Name = {firstName: '', middleName: '', lastName: ''};
names: Name[] = [
    {firstName: 'John', middleName: 'Danny', lastName: 'Smith'}, 
    {firstName: 'Bob', middleName: 'Chris', lastName: 'Lopes'}, 
    {firstName: 'Gary', middleName: 'Tom', lastName: 'Harrison'}
];

.html
<mat-form-field appearence="fill">
        <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="nameSelected">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let name of Names" [value]="name">{{name.firstName}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field> 

 <mat-form-field>  
      <input matInput placeholder="Middle name" [value]="nameSelected.middleName">
    </mat-form-field> 

 <mat-form-field>  
      <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" [value]="nameSelected.lastName">
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: As far as the syntax for the array that was in my code, i just forgot to put it in here but thank you! Also your code changed the 2 input boxes to undefined but i can see that you were almost there as they were changing. I figured it out by changing the value="{{name}}" to [value]="Name" and it worked so thank you for helping me figure it out! If you need anything from me please let me know.

Comment: strange it shouldn't be the case. However I changed my answer to be as you requested. You can accept the answer if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You did provide the answer I was looking for as to how to link the 3 boxes together, with then name instance so I appreciate it. Thank you!